# Facing Problem in drawing UI Previews Dynamic EnumProperty

Tags: python, scripting, interface, append, panel

I am trying to Draw Dynamic Enum property and I started using a one of the templates provided with the blender.

**What I am trying to do:** I have a Folder *Test 2* in which I have 2 Folders -

1. Blends
2. Icons

and a **__ init __.py** in which I am drawing Enum.

I want to import icons from the Icons folder and for each icon, the object should be appended from the Objects.blend file present in the Blends folder.

my icons are cube, sphere, plane, Suzanne...., A cube should be appended when I select cube icon and hit add button, and similarly, the sphere should be appended when clicked on sphere icon (I have used cube, sphere, etc objects as an example, in future I will be replacing these object with the actual object I want to import).**The object to be imported and icon for it has exactly the same name**

If anyone wants to try complete file here is the link - [To get files, Click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ena-07OB8nkyegonaWkFYZEToQDJat4g?usp=sharing)

This is .blend file - [image]

So, this is my__ init __.py file -

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add Object",
    "author": "Rakesh",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}
import bpy
import os
from bpy.types import (
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)
from bpy.props import *
import bpy.utils.previews
from bpy.types import WindowManager

class Object_OT_AddButton(Operator):
    bl_idname = "add.object"
    bl_label = "Add Object"

    def execute(self, context):
        selected_preview = bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].my_previews
        category = context.scene.my_tool.cat

        bpy.ops.wm.append(directory=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Blends" + os.sep + category +
                                                 ".blend" + os.sep + "Object"), filepath=category + ".blend", filename=selected_preview)
        return{'FINISHED'}


def update_category(self, context):
    enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context)


class Categories(PropertyGroup):
    mesh_options = [
        ("Objects", "Objects", '', 0),

    ]

    cat = bpy.props.EnumProperty(

        items=mesh_options,
        description="Select a Category",
        default="Objects",
        update=update_category
    )


def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):

    category = context.scene.my_tool.cat
    # Icons Directory

    directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
       __file__), "Icons" + os.sep + category)

    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    wm = context.window_manager
    directory = wm.my_previews_dir

    # Get the preview collection (defined in register func).
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    print("Scanning directory: %s" % directory)

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the directory for png files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(""):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # generates a thumbnail preview for a file.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)
            icon = pcoll.get(name)
            if filepath in pcoll:
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", pcoll[filepath].icon_id, i))
            else:
                thumb = pcoll.load(filepath, filepath, 'IMAGE')
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
    return pcoll.my_previews


class PreviewsExamplePanel(Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Add object Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_previews"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        wm = context.window_manager
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene.my_tool, "cat", text="Category")

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_icon_view(wm, "my_previews", show_labels=True)

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("add.object", icon="RESTRICT_RENDER_OFF", text="Add")


# We can store multiple preview collections here,
# however in this example we only store "main"
preview_collections = {}


def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager
    from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty,
        EnumProperty,
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
        name="Folder Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default=""
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
        items=enum_previews_from_directory_items,
    )

    import bpy.utils.previews
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = ""
    pcoll.my_previews = ()

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll

    bpy.utils.register_class(Object_OT_AddButton)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Categories)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=Categories)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)


def unregister():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager

    del WindowManager.my_previews

    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Object_OT_AddButton)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Categories)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Issues I am facing -**

1. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\test2_*init*_.py", line 31, in execute
   ".blend" + os.sep + "Object"), filepath=category + ".blend", filename=selected_preview)
   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in **call**
   ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)

RuntimeError: Error: 'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\test2\Blends\Objects.blend\Object': nothing indicated

location: < unknown location >:-1

2. The issue shown above is not reported normally, I mean by this is when I press the button this error is shown, otherwise no errors are shown.

This is what my panel looks like -

[image: Screenshot of Panel]

when I click that add button I get that error, the reason of the error what I believe is some thing is wrong in importing icons as icons are not imported and without selecting any icon i am clicking add and that gives the error -

> RuntimeError: Error: 'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\test2\Blends\Objects.blend\Object':
> nothing indicated

---

I am trying to achieve this type of Panel, In this panel, a particle system is added but I don't want any particle system I just want the object to be appended to the scene when the icon from the dynamic enum is clicked.

**Reference Image -**

[image: Real Grass add-on Panel]

Comment: `category = context.scene.object.cat`  suggests some pointer property `object` is set on `Scene` type to propertygroup above.  But It isn't.

Comment: Ok! @batFINGER I forgot to write PointerProperty but still, it does not solve the problem and it gives this error - ValueError: bpy_struct "Scene" registration error: cat could not register

Comment: Look in system concolse.... does it give a reason it does not register, could it be that the `Categories` class hasn't been registered?  Please make some effort to debug code, or look for answers, before posting each error message.

Comment: I have tried  everything I could do now like I have registered Categories class and removed a few more errors, and now, maybe I am left with the last error that I cannot find a solution of - the error is in line  `category = context.scene.object.cat` and the error report is shown in the console is `AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'object'`. I can't figure out how to get rid of this error as no icons are loaded in the enum(enum is drawn but options(icons) are not visible )

Comment: Please, please, please, please, please  take some time and **look** before posting each error message.                                                                             .  What did you call the pointer property on the scene?

Comment: I am very very sorry please forgive me as I am not very expert at python as you and I am an absolute beginner, so I don't know exactly what to do at this point of time. Should I replace `category = context.scene.object.cat` by `category = context.scene.cat` but this gives this error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Categories") to str`. So I am requesting you could you give me a solution to this problem so that I can better Understand

Comment: `bpy.types.Scene.object = PointerProperty(...`   Then the scene will have `scene.object.cat`  consult the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#propertygroup-example)   Was an absolute beginner at one stage too.  May sound counter-intuitive but consider disconnecting from net for an hour or so and nut these things out.  Coding is logic.  eg Scene has no object property, when you think about it you don't really need someone telling you what this means.

Comment: @batFINGER I tried thinking, and sorry that I could not figure out much - as you said the scene has no object property so should I need to define object property

Comment: @batFINGER could you give me some more hint or solution I will be thankful to you.

Comment: It might help to upload the blender file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @ElliotThomas I had already uploaded the add-on folder itself and google drive link is already mentioned in the question but still, I have uploaded the blend file and this is drive link if you want to try complete folder with icons placed in it- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LsWjtGjiq6dDsE1RZPzM998T3e25amg5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElliotThomas have you tried solving my issue Please

Comment: @ElliotThomas I have updated my question so that it is easy to understand the Issue so Please reread the issue I am facing. and I will be very glad if you help me fix this issue.

Comment: One problem is this. You have lower case here `for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):` and upper case here `enum_items.append((name, name, "", pcoll[filepath].icon_id, I))` and `enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, I))`

Comment: @AFWS very very thank you for pointing the mistake, I improved that but still, icons are not loaded and something is still wrong and I can't figure out as there is no error message thrown out till I press 'add' button and when I press add button `RuntimeError: Error: 'C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\test2\Blends\Objects.blend\Object': nothing indicated` and from this error what I understood is as no option from enum is selected (because icons are not shown) it showed nothing indicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was your file path causing issues. One thing I noticed, it doesn't show under addons ,but didn't take time to figure out why.

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add Object",
    "author": "Rakesh",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}


import bpy, os
from bpy.types import (
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)
from bpy.props import *
import bpy.utils.previews
from bpy.types import WindowManager


class Object_OT_AddButton(Operator):
    bl_idname = "add.object"
    bl_label = "Add Object"

    def execute(self, context):
        selected_preview = context.window_manager.my_previews        
                
        category = context.scene.my_tool.cat
                                                         
        user = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons\\test2\\")
        
        preview_no_ext = selected_preview.split('.')[0]        
        blendpath = category + ".blend"                                                                                                  
        blenddir = os.path.join(user + "Blends" + os.sep + category + ".blend" + os.sep + "Object\\")
          
        bpy.ops.wm.append(directory=blenddir, filepath=blendpath, filename=preview_no_ext)
        
                
        return{'FINISHED'}


def update_category(self, context):
    enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context)


class Categories(PropertyGroup):
    mesh_options = [
        ("Objects", "Objects", '', 0),

    ]

    cat: bpy.props.EnumProperty(

        items=mesh_options,
        description="Select a Category",
        default="Objects",
        update=update_category
    )


def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):

    category = context.scene.my_tool.cat
    
    #Extensions
    extensions = ('.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png')

    # Icons Directory    
    directory = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons\\test2\\Icons\\")
    
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the directory for png files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(extensions):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # generates a thumbnail preview for a file.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)
            icon = pcoll.get(name)
            if filepath in pcoll:
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", pcoll[filepath].icon_id, i))
            else:
                thumb = pcoll.load(filepath, filepath, 'IMAGE')
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
    return pcoll.my_previews


class PreviewsExamplePanel(Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Add object Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_previews"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        wm = context.window_manager
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene.my_tool, "cat", text="Category")

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_icon_view(wm, "my_previews", show_labels=True)

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("add.object", icon="RESTRICT_RENDER_OFF", text="Add")


# We can store multiple preview collections here,
# however in this example we only store "main"
preview_collections = {}


def register():

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
        name="Folder Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default=""
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
        items=enum_previews_from_directory_items,
    )

    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = ""
    pcoll.my_previews = ()

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll

    bpy.utils.register_class(Object_OT_AddButton)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Categories)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=Categories)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)


def unregister():

    del WindowManager.my_previews

    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Object_OT_AddButton)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Categories)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```